# React-Leaflet TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, leaflet

I'm working on a map that asks for permissions for the users location. Than if the location is allowed it finds the users location and then changes the coords of the leaflet map to the coords of the user.But, When compiling the code I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of null

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';



export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      ready: false,
      where: {lat:null, lng:null},
      error: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let geoOptions = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeOut: 20000,
      maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24
    };
    this.setState({ready:false, error: null });
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoSuccess, this.geoFailure, geoOptions);

  }
  geoSuccess = (position) => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);

    this.setState({
      ready:true,
      where: {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng:position.coords.longitude}
    })
  }
  geoFailure = (err) => {
    this.setState({error: err.message});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <MapContainer 
      style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
      center={[this.state.where.lat, this.state.where.lng]} 
      zoom="30" 
      scrollWheelZoom={true}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
    
      </MapContainer>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `<App>` component will mount first and then after that `componentDidMount()` will be called as its name says. The reason you are getting this error is that when `<App>` will be mounted for the first time the `this.state.where` will be null.

To avoid this error you can do the following trick:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';



export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            ready: false,
            where: { lat: null, lng: null },
            error: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let geoOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeOut: 20000,
            maximumAge: 60 * 60 * 24
        };
        this.setState({ ready: false, error: null });
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.geoSuccess, this.geoFailure, geoOptions);

    }
    geoSuccess = (position) => {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);

        this.setState({
            ready: true,
            where: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude }
        })
    }
    geoFailure = (err) => {
        this.setState({ error: err.message });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {( this.state.where.lng != null && this.state.where.lat != null) &&
                    <MapContainer
                        style={{ height: '100%', width: '100%' }}
                        center={[ this.state.where?.lat , this.state.where?.lng]}
                        zoom="30"
                        scrollWheelZoom={true}
                    >
                        <TileLayer
                            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        />

                    </MapContainer>
                }
            </>
        );
    }

}
```

In the above code the `MapContainer` will not render until you will get `this.state.where` in the state.

**UPDATE**

Please look at the previous code as well I updated the checks to render the map.
You can also check the `lng lat` by `console.log()` and if you are not getting them then you can use another package called `@react-native-community/geolocation` which was working for me;

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, StatusBar, Dimensions, Image, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, ToastAndroid, ActivityIndicator,
    LogBox, Keyboard, Modal, TouchableHighlight, PermissionsAndroid, ImageBackground, FlatList, AppState, Linking
} from 'react-native';
import Geolocation from '@react-native-community/geolocation'

export class SignUpScreen extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {

            longitude: '',
            latitude: '',
            locationAccuracy: '',

        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Geolocation.getCurrentPosition((info) => {
            this.setState({
                longitude: info.coords.longitude,
                latitude: info.coords.latitude,
                locationAccuracy: info.coords.accuracy,
            })
        })
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        return (
            <View>
                {this.state.longitude != '' && this.state.latitude != '' &&
                    <>
                        {/* YOUR MAP */}
                    </>
                }
            </View>
        )
    }
}
export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SignUpScreen />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but when I tried this it still gave the same error "Cannot read property 'lat' of null"

Comment: I just saw that you are giving the `null` to `lat lng` in the `state`, I updated the checks in the above code, try it now. If it still gives error then it means its not setting the `lng lat` state somehow, you can check the value of them by `console.log()`

Comment: this worked perfectly and I console.log to check if the coords were found and they were. But, for some reason, it seems like the leaflet map isn't using the coords from this.state.where, and the map centers on the center instead of the coords location. I console.log to see if this.state.where?.lng and lat where being set properly and givin the coords and they were. Don't know whats not allowing the leaflet map to display them.